# How can I modify the interval of the function Image[]?

Tags: image, scaling

I think the default interval is [0,1]. when I have all positives I find it easy to rescale but when I included negative values it doesn't give me the results that I expect. for example how can I change the interval to [-1,1] ?? Thank you very much

Comment: Could you give a simple example of what result you would expect?

Comment: `Rescale[..., {-1, 1}]` doesn't work for you?

Comment: let say I have Image[{{0.5000, 0.7143, -3.0000}, {0, -0.28570, 0} {0, 0, 1.0000}}]                              then what I need would be to have the intensity color go from -1 to 1

Comment: so -3 would correspond to -1 and the largest number 1 would correspond to 1. Pretty much I am trying to normalize my data to [-1,1]. Thank you !

Comment: As mentioned by Rahul Narain `Rescale` should do the job. Be aware that using `Image[]` afterwards still clips the portion of the intensity values outside [0,1] for viewing purposes (not in the internal representation). Using `ImageAdjust` on an image will rescale the values to [0,1].